# If Condition not being triggered in Unity2D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code to change colors based on a theme from playerPrefs, and the theme is correctly displayed in the console when I Debug.Log(), but the ifs are not triggering. In the condition for red, I put two logs, but none of them triggered.

For some reason *using UnityEngine;* and *using UnityEngine.UI* are not displayed in the code box and the final *}* isnt displayed there either. There is also a condition for blue similar to the one for red which I took out here to increase readability.

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

```
public class LoadThemesHome : MonoBehaviour
{

public string theme;

//ALL VARS

public Camera cameraMain;

public Image top;
public Text topText;

public Image timerButton;
public Text timerText;

public Image settingsButton;
public Text settingsText;

public Text info;

public Image bottom;
public Text bottomText;

void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("theme") != null)
    {
        theme = PlayerPrefs.GetString("theme");
    }
    else
    {
        theme = "black";
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("theme", theme);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(theme);

    if (theme == "Black")
    {
        //cameraMain.backgroundColor = new Color(70, 70, 70);

        top.color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        topText.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        timerButton.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        timerText.color = new Color(30, 30, 30);

        settingsButton.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        settingsText.color = new Color(30, 30, 30);

        info.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        bottom.color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        bottomText.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);
    }
    
    else if (theme == "Red")
    {
        Debug.Log("Start");

        //cameraMain.backgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 185);

        top.color = new Color(100, 0, 0);
        topText.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        timerButton.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        timerText.color = new Color(125, 0, 0);

        settingsButton.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        settingsText.color = new Color(125, 0, 0);

        info.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        bottom.color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        bottomText.color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        Debug.Log("Done");
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write these with all lower chars.

for example , write "red" instead of "Red".